# Batch: How do I parse a string containing a filesystem path?

Tags: batch-file, path, text-parsing

I have a string contained in a variable, for example:

```
"C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\SomeFolder\File.jar"
```

I would like to parse File.jar from this string into another variable.  I currently have this somewhat working with the code:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1-6 Delims=\" %%A IN (%string%) DO (set myvariable=%%F)
```

This works as long as the folder path remains the same length.  However, I want to be able to move the program and file and still have everything work right.  Is there any way to parse, just as an idea, from right to left?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply **path modifiers** as follows:

```
set "inputPath=C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\SomeFolder\File.jar"

for %%i in ("%inputPath%") do set fname=%%~nxi

echo %fname%
```

`%%~nx<loop-var>` extracts the filename root (`n`) and filename extension (`x`) from the loop variable; i.e., it extracts the last/filename component from the loop variable's value.
(`%%i` was chosen as the loop variable in this case, but any letter will do.)

---

P.S.: Another frequently used construct is `%%~dp<param-or-loop-var->` to extract the drive spec. (`d`) and the absolute path (without drive spec.) with a terminating `\` (`p`) - this even works for *relative* input paths.
For instance, `%%~dp0` will expand to the absolute path of the folder in which a batch file is located.

A *list of all supported path modifiers* is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true).
(Note that they're only discussed in terms of *parameters*, but they equally work with for-loop variables).

Comment: @endrega My pleasure; glad to hear it; I've added some additional information and a documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could change the script to process all tokens using `*`. And since you're setting your variable with the value of each token, at the end the last token will be assigned to the variable.

```
FOR /f "tokens=* Delims=\" %%A IN (%string%) DO (set myvariable=%%F)
```